# Complex numbers: How to solve the "contradiction"?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$$-1 = i\cdot i = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$$

$$-1 = 1$$

Obviously, something is wrong here, but I can't put my finger on it.

How to solve this "contradiction"?

Comment: Branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$

Comment: This has been asked here *many* times before...

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{-1}$? If you set $\sqrt{-1}:=i$, then it is obvious that $\sqrt{-1 \cdot {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are non-negative.